# Selecting a Button in cpanel Using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

Cannot click a new folder button.
I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("li.action-newfolder")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[a(text(), 'New Folder')]").click()
```

but none works.
This is the html code:

```
<li id="action-newfolder" class="" onclick="return actionHandler('newfolder');">
   <a title="New Folder" href="javascript:void(0)">
     <img alt="" src="img/icons/Folder 1 Add.gif"></img>
     <br></br> New Folder
   </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try any one of the below, It should work for you

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='topnav']//ul//li[@id='action-newfolder']//a//img").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[id='action-newfolder']//a//img//br").click()
```

Comment: tried all the solution yet not working. NoSuchElementException  shown. I am not able to select any of the elements in cpanel file manager.

Comment: @Amritha : Please check below things, Check if the web-element is in another frame? also check if the web-element is visible when we are clicking on the web-element, if not then apply some implicit wait before we click on the web-element.If still the same then can you share the URL if its publicly available or share some more HTML code of before and after web-element and also of you code implementation.

Comment: hope this is enough.<div id="topnav" class="clear"><ul><li id="action-newfile" class="" onclick="return actionHandler('newfile');"><a title="New File" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></li><li id="action-newfolder" class="" onclick="return actionHandler('newfolder');"><a title="New Folder" href="javascript:void(0)"><img alt="" src="img/icons/Folder 1 Add.gif"></img><br></br>
      New Folder
    </a></li><li id="action-copy" class="disabled" onclick="return actionHandler('copy');"><a target="_blank" title="Copy" href="copymove.html"></a></li>

Comment: Sorry, I mean try the Xpath which i have updated in my Answer above.

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[id=\'action-newfolder\']//a//img//br"}' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpKo7wtl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9470)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///tmp/tmpKo7wtl/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:407)

Comment: Is the site publicly available? If yes can you share the url?

Comment: no its not publicly available. Is there anything like we cant use selenium for cpanel???????

Comment: Before the command where we are trying to click on New Folder, insert this command and let  me know what happens. assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("New Folder"));

Comment: Actually this file manager opens in new window....may be thats why i cant find elements.Sorry for the trouble. So now iam trying to finding  a solution to switch to new window.

Comment: Great, so are you able to click on the Web-Element now?

Comment: Good to know that its working, You can use assertion command with page source to know whether the web-element is in our current frame/window, if its then the assertion will pass if not then it will fail. I find this way more easy  when we have frames in our DOM.